# Get ID of selected rows by checkbox selection in View MVC - Jquery

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc

I have list of rows in a view with two checkboxes. When i submit the button I want to get values of that particular row in MVC with jquery. In view i have the following :

```
            @foreach (var item in Model)
            {
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Emp_Id)
                        @*@Html.Hidden("EID", @item.Emp_Id)*@

                    </td>
                    <td>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.LevID) </td>
                    <td>
                        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.EmpName)
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.EmpDept)
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Notes) @Html.Hidden("LveID", @item.LevID)
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <input type="checkbox" id="ChkApproveLve" name="ChkApproveLve" /><label for="ChkApproveLve">Approve</label>
                        <input type="checkbox" id="ChkRejectLve" name="ChkRejectLve" /><label for="ChkRejectLve">Reject</label>
                        <input type="hidden" id="hidLeaveId" value=@item.ID />
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td colspan="3"></td>
                </tr>
            }

        </table>
<div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
            <center>
                <input type="button" name="UpdateLeave" id="BtnUpdateLeave" value="UPDATE" />
            </center>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Using Jquery i try to get values of checkbox checked rows by following :

```
$(document).ready(function(){
        $("#BtnUpdateLeave").click(function () {
            var approve; var reject; var EmpID;
            approve = $("input[name='ChkApproveLve']:checked").length ? "1" : "0";
            reject = $("input[name='ChkRejectLve']:checked").length ? "1" : "0";
            //EmpID = $("#EID").val();
            var LvId = $("#LevID").val();
            //var LvId = $(this).closest('td').find('#LevID').val();
            alert(LvId);
            var szData = $("#frm_UpdateLeave").serialize() + "&Approve=" + approve + "&Reject=" + reject + "&LveID=" + LvId + "&EID=" +  EmpID;
           $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "/Infrastructure/Handler/UpdateLeaveApplication.ashx",
                data: szData,
                success: function (response) {

                    alert('Updated Successfully');
                    location.reload();
                },
                error: function () {
                }
            });

        });
    });
```

When i check Approve/Reject checkboxes of particular row, I want to get data from that row. can any one help me to done this

Thanks in advance..

Comment: Where is `#BtnUpdateLeave` in your HTML?

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan U update the HTML pls check it

Comment: @SomnathKharat Could you explain it where and how  i can use it '.change' ?

Comment: You will have list of rows right and user can select checkbox from multiple rows and click update then how you want to send `LID` because now there will be multiple records to be updated! Do you want to send LIDs as list or how it is?

Comment: @GuruprasadRao : Yes based on user selection. If user select multiple selection then list of values to send, if single record then send it as single

Comment: Are both allowed? I mean accept and reject for same record? if not then have written functionality for selecting only single checkbox per row or u should have used radio button instead of checkbox!! just a doubt!

Comment: No, Only single selection only allowed either Approve or Reject.  i supposed to use only Checkbox only.

Comment: so you want to get `data` on change of `checkbox` state? or on `submit` click?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So to fetch the record on `change` of `checkbox` status you can do as below:

**[DEMO HERE](https://jsfiddle.net/Guruprasad_Rao/131od6ch/)**

Give a classname to each checkbox, say : `leavestatus` and you can catch its status change as below:

```
$(".leavestatus").on('change',function(){
//if($(this).is(":checked")){  //Include if you only want to get details on check and on uncheck do nothing
    var parent= $(this).parent().closest('tr');
    var record="";
    record={'Emp id':  parent.find('td:nth-child(1)').text().trim(),
            'LevID':  parent.find('td:nth-child(2)').text().trim(),
            'EmpName':  parent.find('td:nth-child(3)').text().trim(),
            'Department':  parent.find('td:nth-child(4)').text().trim(),
            'Notes':  parent.find('td:nth-child(5)').text().trim()};
    console.log(record); //check the console for what has been fetched.
    //}
});
```

---

**UPDATE**

[**DEMO**](https://jsfiddle.net/Guruprasad_Rao/131od6ch/1/)

```
var data=[]; //declare a global variable
$(".leavestatus").on('change',function(){
    var parent= $(this).parent().closest('tr');
    if($(this).is(":checked")){
    var record="";
    record={'Emp id':  parent.find('td:nth-child(1)').text().trim(),
            'LevID':  parent.find('td:nth-child(2)').text().trim(),
            'EmpName':  parent.find('td:nth-child(3)').text().trim(),
            'Department':  parent.find('td:nth-child(4)').text().trim(),
            'Notes':  parent.find('td:nth-child(5)').text().trim()};
        data.push(record); //store in a global array
        console.log(data);

    }
    else
    {
         var recordToPopId=parent.find('td:nth-child(2)').text().trim();
         data = data.filter(function( obj ) {
               return obj.LevID !== recordToPopId;
         });//remove from global array on uncheck
         console.log(data);
    }
});
```

Comment: Hi  the above one is working now. I can get individual row records on checkbox change. How can i change it or  maintain data, if for multiple rows checkboxes checked at a time

Comment: Thnk U.Its working, i update the button click as follows :  var approve; var reject;   approve = $("input[name='ChkApproveLve']:checked").length ? "1" : "0"; reject = $("input[name='ChkRejectLve']:checked").length ? "1" : "0";  for (i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {  var szData = $("#frm_UpdateLeave").serialize() + "&Approve=" + approve + "&Reject=" + reject + "&LeaveIDs=" + data[i].LevID; $.ajax({   type: "POST",    url: "/Infrastructure/Handler/UpdateLeaveApplication.ashx",   data: szData, success: function (response) { location.reload(); },  error: function () {  }   });  }  });

Comment: @KaviSuja.. Please append your comment as answer either in my answer or write your own! Its mess in comments.. Anyways.. Happy Coding..

Answer (score 0):

You can write this

```
approve = $("input[name='ChkApproveLve']").is(':checked');
reject = $("input[name='ChkRejectLve']").is(':checked');
```